# Moving UIButton on Y axis while using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm working on a project where I'm using Auto Layout / Universal Story board for the app.

I have a UIButton that I'd like to move to a new position on a certain event. But however without affecting the auto layout. So it will look the same on each device.

I've managed to move the button through this code:

```
int deltaY = 100;

    [ans1 removeConstraints:ans1.constraints];
    ans1.frame = CGRectMake(ans1.frame.origin.x, ans1.frame.origin.y + deltaY, ans1.frame.size.width, ans1.frame.size.height);
```

However the button moves back to it's orginal position within a second or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you remove the constrains in your Button? instead of removing constrains, you can create an IBOutlet of the Button Y Constrain & then change that Y Constrain value

Select the LayoutConstraint you want to change, then control drag it to your .h file

[image: Select the LayoutConstraint you want to change, then control drag it to your .h file]

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *yAxisConstrain;
```

Change your Constrain value like this,

```
yAxisConstrain.constant = 0; //What ever the value you want.
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Never thought of it like that! Just a mildly stupid question. I'm still learning iOS as I've been working on C# before. How do I connect the yAxisConstrain to my UIButton (ans1) as I'm not able to connect it thru interface builder / storyboard.